# Deserialize an ExpandoObject into Object

Tags: c#, json.net, expandoobject

I have an object that will be used with multiple clients.  The object has a set of fixed properties that are common among all clients. Here is an example of what an object may look like:

```
public class Applicant
{
    public string ApplicantId { get; set; }
    public string ProducerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    ...

    public List<dynamic> Information { get; set; }
}
```

We will be receiving this through a Web API POST.  So I have this controller signature:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] dynamic value)
    {
        var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
        dynamic input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Loan>(value,converter);


    }
```

But when I run this code, NewtonSoft keeps giving me the error

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObjectTestAPI.Models.Loan>(string, params Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[])' has some invalid arguments'

Looking around it appears that it is having problem with the dynamic type that is passed in.  So how would I pass in this JSON so I can parse it using the ExpandoObjectConverter?

Comment: in your case, should `value` not type of `string` as you need to `deserialize` later?

Comment: What is `ExpandoObjectConverter`? Also show your Json which you receives and trying to deserialize.

Comment: If I change the value to string I get the error "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String."  The ExpandoObjectConverter is a build in converter from NewtonSoft.

Comment: what happens when you do this: `public void Post([FromBody] Loan value)`? Let the framework deserialize your objects.

Comment: It will deserialize the object just fine, but any dynamic properties that were added won't deserialize into the object because it's a list of dynamic types.  That is why we are using a dynamic type to account for any "extra" properties that may be send across.

Comment: Are you using `Newtonsoft.Json` ? If so, can I see the `Loan` class definition?

Comment: Yes.  Newtonsoft is what is throwing the error

Comment: I use `dynamic` in my models all the time... we need to see the JSON that gets sent to the endpoint and the `Loan` model.

Comment: "any dynamic properties that were added", what exactly do you mean by this? Do you mean that the JSON contains properties that have no place in the Loan object? If so, then what do you expect the conversion from ExpandoObject into Loan would do with those?

Comment: What I mean is that there are some values that are added for every loan object, then there is a List<dynamic> objects that each partner can fill out with their own property/value that only they care about.  So they may best us a "collateralType" :"Car" data that only they care about.  It's these dynamic properties they add, that are not deserialized into the List<dynamic> property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question using dynamic, but it's worth considering avoiding this by using a Dictionary instead to model custom properties. The following works for generic key/value pairs:

```
public class Applicant
{
   ...Standard properties

   public IDictionary<string, object> Custom { get; set; }
}
```

It would accept JSON with arbitrary dynamic fields nested under your "Custom" namespace:

```
{
    "applicationId": "123",
    "producerId": "456",
    "custom": {
        "favoriteAnimal": "turtles",
        "someRandomMetadata": 42,
        "someUnforeseenList": ["foo", "bar"]
    }
 }
```

I've had good luck handling user-defined extension fields this way. It also has the arguable advantage of isolating custom fields into a nested namespace to isolate from built-in data.

Comment: This is the direction we are trying right now.  We are creating an IDictionary instead of a list of dynamic to handle this paring of data.

Answer (score 0):

The framework is very good at serialization and deserialization. There is no reason to use dynamic if you already know the model that's being passed. So you should just simply do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Loan value)
{
    // Loan is already instantiated with your data. You can use the object now.
    return Ok(value); // <-- for example
}
```

Speaking to having `dynamic` objects in your models:

I can't speak for Microsoft's implementation of JSON, but `Newtonsoft.Json` handles this just fine. So let's say your `Loan` model looked like this:

```
public sealed class Loan
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("myDynamicStuff")]
    public dynamic MyDynamicStuff { get; set; }
 }
```

The controller code above would deserialize that just fine without any extra effort.

Comment: The problem is with the last "collection", called Information, on the class of type dynamic. This list can contain 0 to n paired items.  If it was just deserializing into the object that's not a problem, it's all the "extra" items they can send.  I think, I'm just going to move to JToken and move that route.